# Log WPF Data Binding Errors With Log4Net

Tags: wpf, data-binding, log4net

It appears I the data binding errors can be logged via [Bea Stollnitz blog entry](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52).

How can I send Data Binding errors through log4net instead of TraceSources or at the very least route the TraceSource to log4net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement a trace listener that writes log messages with log4net. An example can be found here:

[How to log Trace messages with log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515381/how-to-log-trace-messages-with-log4net)

**EDIT** (Configuration Example):

```
 <system.diagnostics>
     <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
         <listeners>
              <add name="Log4netTraceListener" type="NameSpace.YourClass, YourAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...." />       
         </listeners>
    </trace>
 </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: That completed 1/2 of it, but what about the app.config.  I couldn't the TraceListener's methods called.