# WCF Exception Logging

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Is it possible to log exception like ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded from my WCF service. I know that the message size can be increased in the config but I would also like it logging on my side. I have Log4Net running to catch all unhandled exceptions but it seems this is so not getting logged, so is probably handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, WCF uses system.diagnostics tracing to log exceptions.
See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420538/Simple-steps-to-enable-tracing-in-WCF) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing)

You can redirect system traces to log4net as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515381/how-to-log-trace-messages-with-log4net) question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable Tracing. That can be sent to Nlog. My XYZ.exe.config has a section which looks like that:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error" propagateActivity="true" >
            <listeners>
                <add name="nlog"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <!--source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
            <listeners>
                <add name="nlog" />
            </listeners>
        </source-->
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="nlog" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog" />
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

**NOTE:**
I have the NLog config in the XYZ.exe.config as well!

**EDIT**

I just realized that you were talking about log4net. Not NLog.

If you follow the last [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515381/how-to-log-trace-messages-with-log4net) provided by StephaneT and implement the `Log4netTraceListener` you should be able to use the XYZ.exe.config solution as well.