# Service trace viewer for ordinary windows service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an ordinary C# windows service that crawls web pages and I am experiencing a similar issue to the issue described here: [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209823/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-wcf)

Can I use the Service Trace Viewer Tool for an ordinary windows service (it's not wcf) or is there an alternative tracing utility I can use?

Comment: Add log4net to your service, and log the exceptions to a file.

Comment: @dbugger, unless you are hooking into WCF via extensibility points, you would not ever receive an exception to log.  Log4net does not seem to have a `TraceListener` for this purpose either.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515381/how-to-log-trace-messages-with-log4net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add the listener by adding a `system.diagnostics` configuration section to your `app.config`.  Add the following configuration section and point the log file to a writable path.

App.config:

```
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="c:\drop\servicename wcferror.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true"></trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

If you prefer to log to the event log, you can use `System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener` in lieu of `System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener`.  The `initializeData` is then the log name.